# Integrate Grunt into Rails asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, gruntjs

I would like to exchange / enhance the asset Pipeline with some Grunt tasks. Is there a Way i can integrate grunt into my build process?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might want to check out the gem [half-pipe](https://github.com/d-i/half-pipe)

And here is a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2gaZsFkZ2BQ) explaining it