# Grunt and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gruntjs, assets, bower, grunt-contrib-cssmin

I'm working on using a Grunt workflow to manage my assets in my Rails app rather than Sprockets.

So far, I have my apps JS and CSS both being concatenated and minified into `public/assets/javascripts/application.js` and `public/assets/stylesheets/application.css` respectively.

And also have my Bower components JS and CSS being concatenated and minified into `public/assets/javascripts/vendor.js` and `public/assets/stylesheets/vendor.css` respectively.

Fonts and Images from Bower components are then copied into `public/assets/(images|fonts)`.

This is all well and good but now I need the references to fonts/images within those files to be updated to reflect their new location.

I have looked at cssmin and yes it rewrites file references but I cannot get the file path to change depending upon the type of file being referenced.

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Also, I ahve been reading about Grunt plugins which can read your view files and use those to minify and concatenate files and update the  and  tags in the views for you.

Surely I can't do that in a Rails app? Is there a way I can deal with this in Rails?

Answer (score 0):

This other StackOverflow post may be of help:

[Integrate Grunt into Rails asset pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20025091/integrate-grunt-into-rails-asset-pipeline)

The accepted answer recommends using the [Half Pipe gem](https://github.com/d-i/half-pipe).

The second answer linked to a blog post about a Do-It Yourself solution: [Goodbye, Sprockets! A Grunt-based Rails Asset Pipeline](http://blog.pedago.com/2014/01/21/goodbye-sprockets-a-grunt-based-rails-asset-pipeline/).

I haven't used either solution, but they are worth a try.

Comment: I ahve looked at the half pipe gem but want to try to stick doing it all manually. I have seen the article that you linked to and used that as a guide but it doesn;t quite do the things I am after.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what about the Half Pipe gem didn't work for you? I did some searching for this as well and there's not much information out there.

Comment: I haven't tried it but read into it a lot and watched the video about it. It just seems to be doing too much and I would like to try doing it myself rather than getting that to do it for me. That's all. The problems I am having are basically how to rewrite the URL's inside my CSS and JS files to images etc